# How do I read User Guide in apt-doc on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, package-management, apt-get

I just installed apt-doc package. My question is how do I read the User Guide in this package ? In general how do I use the items from a package once I install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also list the files of the package with `dpkg -L packagename`, and see what's in the `/usr/share/doc/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd open `/usr/share/doc/apt-doc/guide.html` in a web-browser.

In general you read the documentation for the package you are installing, if necessary you get the list of files that are in the package (e.g. `apt-file list packagename`) and decide how to proceed from there.

I believe the most common use of `apt` must be to install software packages. I'd then mostly expect to use `man` to read about what I have installed.

Comment: apt-file is very useful ! Thanks.